# Event drag and drop in full calender should happen only in particular dates

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i am  having  two dates in full calendar , In that '28-04-2015' and '6-05-2015'.
the events which i am having , those events should drop in between the particular dates. In other dates the event should not drop in full calendar.

Comment: you can drag and drop the event in which date you want,,,Like this **http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.1/demos/basic-views.html**

Comment: you can add class to cells with specified dates on which you want to drop events.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `eventConstraint` Limits event dragging and resizing to certain windows of time.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventConstraint: {
            start: '2015-06-15',//change dates according to your needs
            end: '2015-06-29'
    },
    events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2015-06-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2015-06-07',
                end: '2015-06-10'
            }
    ],
});
```

The above function will allow you to drop events between `2015-06-15` to `2015-06-29` you can change the dates according to your needs.

Alternatively you can store restricted dates in event data custom variable, and then check while event is dropped.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2015-06-01',
                end: '2015-06-01',
                restrictedDates: ['2015-06-13', '2015-06-14', '2015-06-15']
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2015-06-07',
                end: '2015-06-07',
                restrictedDates: ['2015-06-15', '2015-06-16', '2015-06-17']
            }
        ],

     eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
            if(!jQuery.inArray(event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), event.restrictedDates)) {
                alert('Restricted Area.');
                revertFunc();               
            } else {
                alert('Free Access');               
            }           
     }
});
```

The second solution is a bit more flexible as you can restrict dates for individual events, but at the end of the day the choice is yours.